# (Xamarin) WinPhone app won't start

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, xamarin

I'm working on a project using Xamarin to build an app for WinPhone and Android.

On the Android device, it works fine.
When I try to run the app on the WinPhone device, the app starts opening and then it closes. On the console I see "TaskHost.exe has exited with code 0."

I don't see any error.
A guy that was working on it before, was using the WinPhone device without problems.
When I started working on it, the only thing I needed to change was the SQLite.WP80 version. He was using 3.8.7.1 and my VS only provided 3.8.8.1.

Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Or how can I see what is wrong? In the console output there is no errors.
I've added a breakpoint in the begining of WinPhone, but it doesnt't arrive there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed your namespace? Check if the startup object in the project setup is set accordingly.

Comment: No, I did not change anything. The project compiles without error. The problem is when I try to run it. On the phone I can see the app opening and after feel seconds it closes.

Comment: And right click on your project, Application - Startup object is set correctly?

Comment: Yes, WinPhone is set as startup

Comment: I don't think this is the case, because I'm not updating project from WP7 to WP8. I'm working on same source code with same device (Nokia Lumia 925) WP 8.0. Before I start working on the project, another programmer were working on this code with same device. When I started working on it, my Visual Studio didn't recognize SQLite.WP80 3.8.7.1, then I change it to SQLite.WP80 3.8.8.1 and it started compiling. When I run it on the device, the app opens and closes. I'm supposing the problem is around the SQLite version, but I don't know.

Comment: Another project I have that do not use SQLite, runs fine on same  device.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem.

By returning the code revision, I found one where the WinPhone project was working on phone.
Then, I started looking for differences.
Someone renamed AppWP.xaml to AppWinPhone.xaml.
Then, on project properties > startup object, it was blank.
I just set the object back and it worked.

(Why not an error message saying what is wrong...)

Thanks!